# Find nearest index of non occurrence of the elements of the tuple in python

Tags: python, templates, indexing, tuples, element

R=[(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (1, 6), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5), (2, 6), (3, 4), (3, 5), (3, 6), (4, 5), (4, 6), (5, 6)]

from the above LIST R, and i need to find nearest indexes for each tuple of its non occurrence of the any elements. I means no values of the tuples are same. and the order of this tuples also fixed.

and finally when we combine the three tuples we should have all the source elements (1,2,3,4,5,6)

Expected Output:

for 0: (0 , 9 , 14): (1,2) (3,4) (5,6) 
for 1: (1 , 6 , 14): (1,3) (2,4) (5,6) 
.
.
.
.
for 4:( 4 , 2 , 12): (1,2) (3,4) (5,6) 
.
.
.and so on

Pls Help...Thanks.

what i have tried is going too huge and i myself not happy with that

```
for j in range(i+1,i+10):
    b=set(Results[j])
    if (len(a&b)==0):

        for k in range(i+10, i+200):
            c=set(Results[k])
            if ( (len(a&c)==0) and (len(b&c)==0) ):

                for l in range(i+200, i+600):
                    d=set(Results[l])
                    if ( (len(a&d)==0) and (len(b&d)==0)  and (len(c&d)==0) ):
```

Comment: Please post the code you have tried. This is not asking a good question.

Comment: for j in range(i+1,i+10):
        b=set(Results[j])
        if (len(a&b)==0):

            for k in range(i+10, i+200):
                c=set(Results[k])
                if ( (len(a&c)==0) and (len(b&c)==0) ):

                    for l in range(i+200, i+600):
                        d=set(Results[l])
                        if ( (len(a&d)==0) and (len(b&d)==0)  and (len(c&d)==0) ):

Comment: My one is going too huge and i look for something in optimized manner...short and neat that's why i don't want to give my views...here. Sorry about that

Comment: Edit the question with the code you have. If you have something that works, but want to ask about optimizations, then that is also a valid question. But we need to see what you have tried already, and formatted correctly. Python code in particular is not suited to the lack of whitespace formatting in comments.

Comment: Oh ok...i have updated the code just now it's really huge and i don't how to pass all the data and everything so i just gave some miniature my problem that's why i didn't post my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gets rid of one of your nested loops. I don't know where you are getting the `i` values from, or why you are using such large ranges on your inner loops.

```
R = [(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (1, 6), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5), (2, 6), (3, 4), (3, 5), (3, 6), (4, 5), (4, 6), (5, 6)]
# keep track of the indices where tuple elements are disjoint
matches = {}
# loop over R
for index in range(len(R)):
  # track the elements seen so far
  elements = set(R[index])
  # track the index where elements were seen
  matches[index] = [index]
  # loop over subsequent items
  for _index in range(index, len(R)):
    # if the tuple has all items not already seen, record it
    if elements.isdisjoint(set(R[_index])):
      elements = elements.union(R[_index])
      matches[index] += [_index]
# discard anything that does not have all six items
final_matches = {k: v for k, v in matches.viewitems() if len(v) == 3}
```

Comment: Wow...Perfectly alright and i just did one change in last line matches.viewitems() to matches.items() may be due to version conflicts or something. However, it's working fine and perfect. Thank u so much for your lightning response and Tones of thanks indeed.

Comment: Bro...similar one but slight change in that pls help R=[(1,10,14,34),(2,5,19,21),(3,7,31,32),(1,9,12,31),(2,10,11‌​,22),(4,8,14,32),(13‌​,15,19,34),(1,5,15,2‌​0),(3,26,19,25),(4,1‌​7,19,21),(4,1‌​7,20,21)]


For each tuple in R, find the next index of each elements with the same element position where other elements should not be present in both tuples.

FOR Index 0 and 1 here is expected sample results

0: 4,5,6,7  
1: 2,5,6,8
.
.
.
.
.
so on   or check my post here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44558290/compare-tuples-and-find-next-index-in-its-same-position-in-python