# Compare Tuples and find next index in it's same position in python

Tags: python, compare, tuples, element

```
R=[(1,10,14,34),(2,5,19,21),(3,7,31,32),(1,9,12,31),(2,10,11‌​,22),(4,8,14,32),(13‌​,15,19,34),(1,5,15,2‌​0),(3,26,19,25),(4,1‌​7,19,21),(4,1‌​7,20,21)]
```

For each tuple in R, find the next index of each elements with the same element position where other elements should not be present in both tuples.

**FOR Index 0 and 1 here is expected sample results**

```
0: 4,5,6,7  
1: 2,5,6,8
.
.
.
.
.
so on
```

*Here is my code is going too detail and too lengthy and taking too long to run for my actual project. so i gave a sample above pls help me to drive this in a optimistic way.., to achieve the speed.*

```
for j in range(i+1,i+10):
        b=set(Results[j])
        if (len(a&b)==0):

            for k in range(i+10, i+200):
                c=set(Results[k])
                if ( (len(a&c)==0) and (len(b&c)==0) ):

                    for l in range(i+200, i+600):
                        d=set(Results[l])
                        if ( (len(a&d)==0) and (len(b&d)==0)  and (len(c&d)==0) ):

                            for m in range(i+500, i+1000):
                                e=set(Results[m])
                                if ( (len(a&e)==0) and (len(b&e)==0)  and (len(c&e)==0)   and (len(d&e)==0) ):

                                    for n in range(i+1000, i+2000):
                                        f=set(Results[n])
                                        if ( (len(a&f)==0) and (len(b&f)==0)  and (len(c&f)==0)   and (len(d&f)==0)   and (len(e&f)==0) ):

                                            for o in range(i+2000, i+3000):
                                                g=set(Results[o])
                                                if ( (len(a&g)==0) and (len(b&g)==0)  and (len(c&g)==0)   and (len(d&g)==0)   and (len(e&g)==0)  and (len(f&g)==0) ):              

                                                        for p in range(i+3000, XRUN):
                                                            h=set(Results[p])
                                                            if ( (len(a&h)==0) and (len(b&h)==0)  and (len(c&h)==0)   and (len(d&h)==0)   and (len(e&h)==0)  and (len(f&h)==0)  and (len(g&h)==0)):              

                                                                CN=CN+1
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Walk through how you get `1: 2, 5, 6, 8`, if I follow your logic then I get `1: 4, 7, 8, 9`. And I get no solution for `2`. Are your indexes off by one, e.g. should `0: 3, 4, 5, 6`?

Comment: when u run for index 0 in R Then 1 become its 0 and for 1 the 2 become the 0 i mean the starting range.

Comment: in simple just find the previous index of the same position and the only condition in both tuples the other values should not be present. that's all

Comment: Sorry but I'm going to have to give up. I'm just not following and you are not providing enough clarity for me.

Comment: never mind...just do your way and give me the lines for this 1: 4, 7, 8, 9 atleast from there i can modify some

Comment: as simple as that just find the previous index where no other values are not present in both tuples...don't know how to explain better than this.